# I am getting an error "The device is not ready" while accessing files from file directory

Tags: asp.net, powerpoint

I want to get total slide count of all ppt files in a folder. The code that i used is working on my local machine, but it is giving an error"The device is not ready" when running on server/live website.

Following is the code i've used:

```
 public void getslidecount()
    {
        int slidesCount = 0;
        int totalslidesCount = 0;



        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(txtpath.Text))
        {
            string ext = file.ToString();
            ext = Path.GetExtension(ext);

            if (ext == ".ppt" || ext == ".pptx")
            {
                Presentation ppt = new Presentation();

                ppt.LoadFromFile(file);
                slidesCount = Convert.ToInt32(ppt.Slides.Count);

                totalslidesCount += slidesCount;
            }
        }


        txtcount.Text = totalslidesCount.ToString();
        lblcount.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btngo_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getslidecount();
    }
```

Error is on line " foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(txtpath.Text))"

Also note, i've imported dll of Spire for Presentation "using Spire.Presentation;

Thanks for help in advance!